# Training a gensim Word2Vec model after saving on a Hindi dataset

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to re-train my word2vec model on a bigger dataset, I've saved the model using `model.save('ikshan_word2vec.bin')`, and now I am loading this .bin file in my colab, where I have the dataset stored in corpus (Already pre-processed).

When I try to retrain my model using `update=True`, and I print my vocabulary size before training and after training, it shows no change in the length.

Here is a snippet of my new corpus as well to ensure that its of right form.

[image]

This is what I am trying to do, also this code executed in 0.0 seconds.

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

# Load the pre-saved Word2Vec model
pretrained_model = KeyedVectors.load('/content/ikshan_word2vec.bin')

# Check the initial vocabulary size
print(len(pretrained_model.wv.key_to_index))

# New set of sentences to train on
new_sentences = corpus

# Update the vocabulary with new sentences
pretrained_model.build_vocab(new_sentences, update=True)

# Train the model on the new sentences
pretrained_model.train(new_sentences, total_examples=len(new_sentences), epochs=pretrained_model.epochs)

# Check the updated vocabulary size
print(len(pretrained_model.wv.key_to_index))
```

Comment: How much larger is the 2nd batch? Are you sure the 2nd batch has new words, and many examples of each new word? Why not just train a new model with the entire combined dataset?